# systemd root authentication every new shell session

Tags: debian, systemd, polkit

I'm running Debian stable 9.3. Since last month I have a problem with systemd behaviour. I suppose it's not Debian specific--it's rather systemd.

Every new instance of shell session I'm asked to type root password. (I'm logged in as regular user) It is regardles of shell type. Either TTY1 or graphical terminal emulators it's the same. Before I'll be able to see my prompt I got a message (partly in Polish, I couldn't swith it to english).

```
 ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
 Wymagane jest uwierzytelnienie, aby zarządzać plikami usług lub jednostek systemu.
 Authenticating as: root
 Password: 
 ==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
 Removed /etc/systemd/system/default.target.
 Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target → /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.
 ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
 Wymagane jest uwierzytelnienie, aby ponownie wczytać stan systemd.
 Authenticating as: root
 Password: 
 ==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
 ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
 Wymagane jest uwierzytelnienie, aby zarządzać plikami usług lub jednostek systemu.
 Authenticating as: root
 Password: 
 ==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
 Removed /etc/systemd/system/default.target.
 Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target → /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.
 ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
 Wymagane jest uwierzytelnienie, aby ponownie wczytać stan systemd.
 Authenticating as: root
 Password: 
 szymon@t60:~$
 ==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
```

This Polish phrases are about authentication needed by systemd to perform its tasks.

I can't ignore this, because if I won't type the password for a while I got message:

```
Password: Failed to set default target: Method call timed out
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
```

And shell becomes kind of inactive--I can't type anything, although prompt is visible.

The /var/log/auth.log after starting new terminal emulator window
    Dec 16 08:12:44 t60 polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2375:3585428 (system bus name :1.86 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 4 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale pl_PL.UTF-8)

The problem occured when I issued the following command without SUDO:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

As far as I remember it asked for the root password and since then I got this annoying issue.

What I was trying to accomplish was login to my system in non-GUI mode, not by GDM or whatever I'm using now. That command was part of some random tutorial about systemd and non-GUI login.

Since last month I discovered a "workaround". I can always hit `Ctrl - D` twice and everything works anyway:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Wymagane jest uwierzytelnienie, aby zarządzać plikami usług lub jednostek systemu.
Authenticating as: root
Password: 
** (process:20702): ERROR **: Got unexpected EOF while reading from controlling terminal.
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
Failed to set default target: Access denied
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Wymagane jest uwierzytelnienie, aby zarządzać plikami usług lub jednostek systemu.
Authenticating as: root
Password: 
** (process:20708): ERROR **: Got unexpected EOF while reading from controlling terminal.
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
Failed to set default target: Access denied
~ $
```

...but it's annoying and also frustrating because I'm unable to understand what's going on.
Especialy, because I've set default target to graphical again, but it didn't help:

```
~ $ systemctl get-default
graphical.target
```

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this issue and why I'm getting those messages?

Comment: Have you tried repeating the step to set the default target but this time with sudo?

Comment: Sure. It even works in expected manner in terms of loging in a tty, however after I log in those messages are still present. `    $ sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
    [sudo] password: 
    Removed /etc/systemd/system/default.target.
    Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target → /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.`